# How to hide the "Parameter" site of a finished job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parameters, passwords, hide, jobs

I'm using a password as a parameter and unfortunately it is displayed in the "`Parameter`" site of a finished job, which is located at "`localhost:8080/view/BUILD/job/Jobname/Jobnumber/parameters/`". See screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to hide the "`Parameter`" site or the parameter itself?

Comment: Not sure if it works but have you tried this one? 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin

Comment: thx, this plugin helped me to hide my password :)